# how to change user id for user name in url? - php

Tags: php, facebook, url-shortener

when you create an acount on facebook, you get something like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100008513864411
```

but...

after a while, it changes like that:

```
https://www.facebook.com/taxi.rs.5
```

but...

if you put the first link, still working!

How can I do something like that?

Comment: You can use an htaccess file to shorten url's. Try checking this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Comment: the url doesn't open but thanks... I've searched in google, and it work if you put the the second link, htaccess read it. But if you put the first link in browser, work but the link doesn't change to the second format, I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did...
File **.htaccess** (I didn't knew I had to create it in the root)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /mydomain/

    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3

</IfModule>
```

so... when I use:

```
localhost/mydomain/w/y/t
//appache execute: http://localhost/mydomain/index.php?var1=w&var2=y&var3=t
```

that's it